# android publish apk incompatiblility

Tags: android, apk, publish, incompatibility

I have a problem, I published my apk but people can not download it just says that it is not compatible with the devices tested my friends:
My friends have a "normal HDPI" screen.

**This is my manifest :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.switchart.game"
android:versionCode="5"
android:versionName="1.0">
......
......
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<supports-screens
android:smallScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:anyDensity="true" />
<uses-sdk 
android:minSdkVersion="7"
android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>
</manifest>
```

**I publish on the following information:**

```
versionCode: 5
versionName: 1.0
Taille : 48M
Localisée en : par défaut, English, French
Autorisations : android.permission.INTERNET, android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS, android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER, android.permission.VIBRATE
Fonctionnalités : android.hardware.screen.portrait, android.hardware.touchscreen
Aucun fichier d'extension principal
Aucun fichier d'extension correctif
« moins
Niveau d'API : 7-17+
Écrans compatibles : small-xlarge
Textures OpenGL : toutes
Désactiver
```

when I press this command aapt dump badging  I have this :

```
package: name='com.switchart.game' versionCode='5' versionName='1.0'
application-label:'Switch art'
application-label-en:'Switch art'
application-label-fr:'Switch art'
application-icon-120:'res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png'
application-icon-160:'res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png'
application-icon-240:'res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png'
application-icon-320:'res/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png'
application: label='Switch art' icon='res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png'
launchable-activity: name='com.switchart.game.Main' label='Switch art' icon=''
uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.touchscreen'
uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.screen.portrait'
uses-permission:'android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission:'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER'
uses-permission:'android.permission.VIBRATE'
sdkVersion:'7'
targetSdkVersion:'10'
uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-implied-permission:'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE','requested WR
ITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
main
wallpaper
other-activities
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large' 'xlarge'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales: '--_--' 'en' 'fr'
densities: '120' '160' '240' '320'
```

I noticed a problem in food publish it compatible screens: small-xlarge out I did something compatible with all widths!
aapt dump badging : I have  this 'small' 'normal' 'large' 'xlarge'
Why the difference? what's the problem?

I do not want to use instead of "compatible-screens" "supports-screens" because I want to be compatible sdk version 7!

See a problem with my manifest file?
Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you want this application to work on all screens? If so, get rid of the supports-screens directive all together - the default is all. Or were there certain screen types you *did* want to bar?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the xlarge screen atribute to your supported screens tag:

```
android:xlargeScreens="true"
```

Comment: android:xlargeScreens="true" does not exist in version android 2.1 !

Comment: HTC Desire can not download application from google play. How to know why it don't want to download ?

Comment: you can built your app with higher than 2.1 and specify your minimum sdk it should be available for. Im building all my apps right now with 4.1sdk and some even have a minimum sdk of 1.6. hope that helps